# How could I resolve python - parallel issue?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I wrote a code which is something like this:

```
import time
import pp

class gener(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __call__(self):
        return self    

    def __iter__(self):
        n = self.n
        for i in range(n):
            time.sleep(2)
            yield i

def gen():
    return gener(3)

job_server = pp.Server(4)
job = job_server.submit(
                        gen, 
                        args=(),
                        depfuncs=("gener",),
                        modules=("time",),
                        )

print job()
```

following @zilupe useful comment I got the following output:

```
<__main__.gener object at 0x7f862dc18a90>
```

How can I insert `class gener` iteration to parallel?

I'd like to run it parallel with other functions.
I need this generator like class, because I want to replace an other code from a modul of a rather complicated program package and it would be hard to refactor that code.

I tried a lot of thing without any success so far.
I made a rather solid investigation on this site, but I couldn't find the right answer suitable for me.
Anybody, any help?
Thank you.

**ADDITION:**

According to @zilupe useful comments some additional information:

The main purpose is to parallelize the iteration inside of `class gener`:

```
 def __iter__(self):
        n = self.n
        for i in range(n):
            time.sleep(2)
            yield i
```

I only created of `gen()` function because I wasn't be able to figure out, how could I use it directly in `parallel.submit()`.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question but you get the error because `depfuncs` has to be a tuple of functions, not strings -- the line should be: `depfuncs=(gener,),`

Do you realise that function `gen` is only creating an instance of `gener` and is not actually calling it?

What are you trying to parallelise here -- creation of a generator or iteration over the generator? If it's the iteration, you should probably create the generator first, pass it to `gen` in args and then in `gen` iterate over it:

```
def gen(g):
    for _ in g:
        pass

job_server.submit(gen,args=(gener(3),),...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, perhaps it's because of a bit tiredness, however as you mentioned this is still not the answer to my problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's hard to tell what the purpose of `gener` is but I've updated the answer with another thing to check.

Comment: Good point! I'd like to run the iteration parallel, not the creation of generator. Actually the purpose of gen only avoiding the "AttributeError: type object 'gener' has no attribute 'func_name'" error message. Could you, please give me some solution, how I can use the gener class directly for the parallelize the iteration?

Comment: I tried your logical solution i.e. sending the generator object into the parallel.submit(), I didn't succeed to iterate with it, I only got the same number (actually "2").